# mongo - ruby connection problem

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have installed mongo and bson_ext
now I have created a .rb file with the following contents ::

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost").db("mydb")
db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost", 27017).db("mydb")
```

However I am getting following error on running the code

```
yuzaki@ubuntu:~$ ruby firstruby.rb
/home/ryuzaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongo-1.2.0/lib/mongo/connection.rb:451:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
    from /home/ryuzaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongo-1.2.0/lib/mongo/connection.rb:554:in `setup'
    from /home/ryuzaki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mongo-1.2.0/lib/mongo/connection.rb:98:in `initialize'
    from firstruby.rb:4:in `new'
    from firstruby.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Please help!

Comment: Is your mongo server actually running? What happens when you do a `telnet localhost 27017`?

Comment: If mongo isn't running, just do in an another terminal: `mongod`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is definitely due to your mongo server not running. Since you're on Ubuntu, try doing a `sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start` and then see if your code works.

Comment: there is no mongodb in my init.d.

Comment: Do you have mongo installed on your machine (I don't just mean the gem, I mean an actual mongo server). If not, you'll need to install it: `sudo apt-get install mongodb`.

Comment: **sudo invoke-rc.d mongodb restart** on any debian system

Answer (score 43):

had this happen several times now, and here is the solution that works for me:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair
sudo start mongodb
sudo status mongodb
```

Comment: I had a similar problem after an unclean shutdown and removing the lock solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Globalkeith! Had just run an update on ubuntu and restarted. Naughty ubuntu.

Comment: I think its `mongod` not `mongodb`

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this due to my /etc/hosts file not containing an entry for "localhost" - consequently Ruby couldn't resolve "localhost". I suppose you can hardcode 127.0.0.1 into your code rather than "localhost" - or fix /etc/hosts to contain:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac and used Brew, restarting the service solved it for me:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

You can find this info by running `brew info mongodb`.

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, using brew I found that `brew info mongodb` and then using then

`ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents` or `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is simply not enough space.

> exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for
>   journals, terminating