# How to check if Mongodb is properly installed

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDb yesterday on a Mac Snow Leopard and got the following error message

```
Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
```

when trying to run some tests in Rails that used a mongodb.

Another SO question [mongo - ruby connection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837427/mongo-ruby-connection-problem) about the same error message had an answer that recommended removing the lock file

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

but when I run that command i'm getting

```
 No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how I can figure out how to get it working or see if it's properly installed?

Comment: Is the mongod process running? you can check with `pgrep -fl mongod` or `ps ax|grep mongod`

Comment: The first command didn't work, but the second one returned: 9729 s003  R+     0:00.00 grep mongod    Any idea what I should do?

Comment: It looks like the `mongod` process is NOT running, so you should start it first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to run mongodb on Mac OS is:

Download binary package from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads, for me, I am using lastest 64 bit version (http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz)

1. `mkdir -p $HOME/opt`
2. `cd $HOME/opt`
3. `wget http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz` to download the latest (2.0.2 for now) 64 bit binary package for Mac OS
4. `tar xf mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz -C $HOME/opt` to unpack the package, and it will be unpacked to `$HOME/opt/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2`
5. `mkdir -p $HOME/opt/mongodata` to create the data directory for mongodb
6. `$HOME/opt/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongod --dbpath=$HOME/opt/mongodata --logpath=$HOME/opt/mongod.log` to start the mongodb daemon
7. Then you can run `$HOME/opt/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongo` to connect to your local mongodb service

You can also have http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+OS+X as additional reference

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a try. Since i already downloaded it I'm not sure i can go back and do the binary package solution you wrote

Comment: @Michael It looks like you have already installed mongodb with MacPorts, so you can skip steps 1-4, and just create data directory for mongodb, and run `mongod --dbpath=$HOME/opt/mongodata --logpath=$HOME/opt/mongod.log` to start the server.

Answer (score 4):

It's not running mongod. You need to start it, probably with a script so you can control how it starts. The script I use on my mac looks like: `mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf &`.

At this point I can't remember if the install came with /etc/mongodb.conf, or if I put it there myself. It's fairly simple. I store my data/log in my user folder (this is obviously a development environment):

```
dbpath = /Users/me/data/
logpath = /Users/me/mongo.log

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

You'll also need to create your data folder, if it doesn't exist.