# How to browse data in MongoDB in Mac OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, mongodb, mongoid

When I am using PostgreSQL, I am accustomed to use terminal for browsing data stored in DB tables.

Is there any similar way to do it for MongoDB? I have used [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204296/how-to-check-if-mongodb-is-properly-installed) for MongoDB installation on Mac.

Thanks

Comment: there is the mongo shell http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/

Comment: (If you're looking for something more graphical eventually, you might try http://genghisapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB bin directory contains an executable called 'mongo' which is an interactive shell (similar to 'psql' in PostgreSQL)

You can read more about how to use it [HERE.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/mongo/)

To get started, you can type

```
> help
```

To switch to a specific database, just type:

```
> use db-name
      ^^^^^^^ replace with your db name.

> db.help()
> db.collectionName.help()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ replace with your collection name
```

You can do this from any machine not just the one mongod is running on but then you connect via:

```
mongo hostname:port/dbname
```

for example

```
mongo myMongoDBserver:27017/foobardb
```

Answer (score 0):

command 'mongo' will open mongo shell for you, there you can use database commands

Comment: `mongod` is the server, you'll want `mongo`

Comment: yep messed up, mongod will start the server and mongo will open shell. Thanks @beny23

Answer (score 0):

First start `mongod` process in a terminal tab. In other terminal tab or window simply start `mongo`.

`mongod` is mongo daemon which establishes connections and listens to requests. `mongo` is the javascript shell where you can have your interactive mongodb queries.

Rest is best explained in the link @Asya Kamsky provided in his answer.