# localhost Mongo::ConnectionFailure but I can access web console

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm having trouble with the ruby mongodb adapter.

When I do

```
client = Mongo::MongoClient.new
```

I get `Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)`

The server seems to be running since I can use the `mongo` shell command and when I visit `localhost:28017` in my browser I see this:

[image]

Comment: Might need to specify what database you are connecting to?

Comment: Just to add to @pje, some hints on fixing this issue are in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837427/mongo-ruby-connection-problem?rq=1)